# foreach error "can't find function "adaptIntegrate" even when I use .packages="cubature"

Tags: r, foreach

I have this weird error that usually occurs when you don't specify the necessary packages in the foreach function. But I did and it still gives me the same error.

my code is this:

```
for (i in 1:(length(as.matrix(x1))/2)) {
    for (j in 1:(length(as.matrix(x2))/2)){
      if ((i %% 100 == 0) & (j == 1)) {
        print(c(i, j))
      }
      repr1 = function(theta1,theta2) {
        sigma1^2 * exp(-0.5 * sum((cbind(c(cos(theta1), sin(theta1)), c(-sin(theta1), cos(theta1))) %*% as.numeric(x1[i,]) -
                                     cbind(c(cos(theta2), sin(theta2)), c(-sin(theta2), cos(theta2))) %*% as.numeric(x2[j,]))^2) / l1)
      }
      
      repr2 = function(theta1,theta2) {
        sigma2^2 * exp(-0.5 * sum((cbind(c(cos(theta1), sin(theta1)), c(-sin(theta1), cos(theta1))) %*% as.numeric(x1[i,]) -
                                     cbind(c(cos(theta2), sin(theta2)), c(-sin(theta2), cos(theta2))) %*% as.numeric(x2[j,]))^2) / l2)
      }
      
      integrands <- list(
        function(theta) repr1(theta[1], theta[2]) * cos(theta[1]) * cos(theta[2]) + repr2(theta[1], theta[2]) * sin(theta[1]) * sin(theta[2]),
        function(theta) -repr1(theta[1], theta[2]) * cos(theta[1]) * sin(theta[2]) + repr2(theta[1], theta[2]) * sin(theta[1]) * cos(theta[2]),
        function(theta) -repr1(theta[1], theta[2]) * sin(theta[1]) * cos(theta[2]) + repr2(theta[1], theta[2]) * sin(theta[2]) * cos(theta[1]),
        function(theta) repr2(theta[1], theta[2]) * cos(theta[1]) * cos(theta[2]) + repr1(theta[1], theta[2]) * sin(theta[1]) * sin(theta[2])
      )
      
      results = foreach(integrand = integrands, .combine = 'c',.packages = 'cubature') %dopar% {
        adaptIntegrate(integrand, c(0, 0), c(2 * pi, 2 * pi), maxEval = 100)$integral
      }
}
}
```

I still get the error

Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "adaptIntegrate""

even if I use

```
results = foreach(integrand = integrands, .combine = 'c',.packages = 'cubature') %dopar% {
install.packages("cubature")
        cubature::adaptIntegrate(integrand, c(0, 0), c(2 * pi, 2 * pi), maxEval = maxEval)$integral
      }.
```

I really don't know what is missing and would be very happy if someone knew a relief of this.

Comment: Do you running running `library(cubature)` before you run your code?